# What is inside ViewBag?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controllerbase.viewbag(v=vs.118).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1), there are `ViewBag.MyMessageToUsers` and `ViewBag.AnswerText`. In the [ASP.net/mvc tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/adding-a-view), there are `ViewBag.Message`, `ViewBag.NumTimes` and such. What are the data types of these properties? And where in the solution are they declared?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ViewBag is a [dynamic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx) collection.  In your controller you can put whatever you want in it and call it from your View.  They can be whatever objects and whatever types you want.

The link you provided to the [MSDN Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controllerbase.viewbag(v=vs.118).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) is providing an example of this.

If you have the following in your controller:

```
ViewBag.Something = thing;
```

`thing` is declared somewhere, and you are accessing it here.  You don't declare `ViewBag`, and `Something` gets automatically declared when you assign `thing` to it.

Comment: So it's "declared" in the controller?

Comment: Yes, you have to set it .. essentially declare it in the controller

Answer (score -1):

> What are the data types of these properties?

Answer: There is no type for ViewBag! It is just like a Bag and you can put lots of stuff in it.

> Where in the solution are they declared?

Answer: You could declare the type when you want use your data inside the ViewBag
with converting to types.